# Delete all records with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

**AAA** with the columns:

```
id  |  text
```

**BBB** with the columns (`aaa_id` is a foreign key => `id` from the previous table - **AAA**):

```
id  |  text  | aaa_id
```

and **CCC** with the columns (`bbb_id` is a foreign key => `id` from the previous table - **BBB**):

```
id  |  text  | bbb_id
```

Now when I delete a record from the table **AAA** I want to delete all the records from the table **BBB** which are `aaa_id = AAA.id` and also delete all the records from the table **CCC** which are connected to the records I'd like to delete from **BBB** (so they have `bbb_id` equal to `BBB.id` of the records which are `aaa_id` equal to `AAA.id`).

I've tried to user inner join but I had no luck. Meanwhile, I select all the records with PHP and delete them separately.

The tables are MyISAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DELETE AAA, BBB, CCC
    FROM AAA
    LEFT JOIN BBB ON BBB.aaa_id = AAA.id
    LEFT JOIN CCC ON CCC.bbb_id = BBB.id
```

You could use INNER JOIN as well, if there's always child records in each table. Or you can set up ON DELETE CASCADE in your foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) option.

> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table. Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported. Between two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the dependent rows from another table you have to use a table engine, which supports foreign keys.

Then set the `ON DELETE` action to `CASCADE`

More documentation could be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

Create the foreign keys with `on delete cascade` that way when you delete from the parent table all child rows will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

**Foreign Key constraints as ON DELETE CASCADE**

when u creating table follow syntax like the following example,

```
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `ids` (`ids`)
CONSTRAINT `foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`ids`)
REFERENCES `table2` (`ids`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

**Note:** You need to use InnoDB storage engine, he default MyISAM storage engine not support foreign keys relation.

otherwise use inner join for deletion